# .NET can't resolve dependency version conflict ("X is defined in an assembly that is not referenced")... but only sometimes

Tags: .net

1. Project **BaseApp** is a .NET Standard 2.0 library.
2. Its PackageReferences include **LaunchDarkly.ServerSdk** version **5.13.1**, and **LaunchDarkly.ServerSdk.Redis** version **1.1.1**.
3. There's a transitive package reference from **LaunchDarkly.ServerSdk.Redis** to **LaunchDarkly.ServerSdk** version **5.6.4** - that being the *minimum* version that **LaunchDarkly.ServerSdk.Redis** requires.

The above works just fine. We've never had a problem when we updated **BaseApp**'s dependency on **LaunchDarkly.ServerSdk** to any version in the range 5.6.5...5.13.1; it correctly resolves the transitive dependency to use the higher version.

However, now I'm testing a prerelease version: I have updated **BaseApp**'s dependency on **LaunchDarkly.ServerSdk** to version **5.14.0-alpha.1**. Doing that caused build errors like this:

`error CS0012: The type 'IFeatureStoreFactory' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'LaunchDarkly.ServerSdk, Version=5.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f86add69004e6885'. [/app/src/BaseApp/BaseApp.csproj]`

The type IFeatureStoreFactory is an interface that is defined in **LaunchDarkly.ServerSdk** and implemented in **LaunchDarkly.ServerSdk.Redis** (that's why the latter has a dependency on the former in the first place, so it knows what the interface is that it's implementing). And the interface is definitely present in the newer version - there are no backward-incompatible changes. But it's behaving as if nothing but the interface type *from the 5.6.4 version* is acceptable.

This is a library, not an application (despite the "App" in the name), so binding redirects are not involved. Again, this worked like a charm until just now, so I'm sure there's some difference I just haven't noticed. The new version is a prerelease version but I can't think why that would matter - 5.14.0-alpha.1 would be lower than 5.14.0, but it's still higher than 5.6.4.

I hope this isn't a duplicate - there are lots of "defined in an assembly that is not referenced" questions, but none of the ones I've seen match this situation.

Comment: I thought I might get some clues by looking at `package.assets.json` before and after my change (since the package restore does succeed - the error is during compilation). But I don't see a difference there; in both the earlier version that works, and the current one that fails, it shows the newest version of `LaunchDarkly.ServerSdk` at the top level (like, that's what it's actually loading), and the transitive dependency from `LaunchDarkly.ServerSdk.Redis` to `LaunchDarkly.ServerSdk` is just what it was originally declared as (5.6.4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! The answer is that one of those versions is strong-named and the other isn't - so .NET does not consider them to be the same assembly name.